# Why I am getting a space character in my program in the place of third last character?

Tags: c

Why I am getting a space character in my program in the place of third last character?
Even if I change the string str variable I get the same result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void parser(char array[])
{
    int a, b;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(array); i++) {
        if (array[i] == '>') {
            a = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int j = a; j < strlen(array); j++) {
        if (array[j] == '<') {
            b = j;
        }
    }
    for (int p = 0, q = a + 1; p < b - a - 1, q < b; p++, q++) {
        array[p] = array[q];
        array[b - a] = '\0';
        printf("%c", array[p]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "<h1>hello there i am programmer.</h1>";
    parser(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you get and what do you expect to get as output?

Comment: What is the purpose of this line? `array[b-a]='\0';` `a` and `b` are index values of `>` and `<`. The difference of these indices doesn't seem very useful. Also why is this in the loop when these values don't change?

Comment: This is a strange condition for your loop: `p<b-a-1,q<b` Do you know what the comma operator does? What do you expect to be result of this expression?

Comment: I suggest you run your program in a debugger and check where the execution comes along. Also watch the content of the variables.

Comment: Maybe your intention might more clear if you used `string.h` functions, which includes lots of stuff that may be helpful; _eg_ `strcspn`, `strrchr`, `strpbrk`, `strchr`.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things that could be written better in the code but they do not affect the result.
The line that produces the unexpected outcome is:

```c
        array[b-a]='\0';
```

When this `for` loop starts...

```c
    for(int p=0,q=a+1;p<b-a-1,q<b;p++,q++){
        array[p]=array[q];
        array[b-a]='\0';
        printf("%c",array[p]);
    }
```

... the values of `a` and `b` are `3` and `32`.

The statement `array[b-a]='\0';` puts the NUL terminator character at position `29` in `array`.

The loop starts with `p=0`, `q=4` (`a+1`) and repeats until `p` reaches `28` and `q` reaches `31` (`q<b`)<sup>*</sup>.

When `p` is `25`, `q` is `29` and `array[29]` has been repeatedly set to `'\0'` on the previous iterations, therefore `'\0'` is copied at position `25` and printed on screen.

You should set the NUL terminator only once, after the loop. And the right position for it is `b-a-1`, not `b-a`; you expressed this correctly in the `for` initialization (`p=0`) and exit condition (`p<b-a-1`).

All in all, the code around the last `for` loop should be like this:

```c
    for(int p=0, q=a+1;q<b;p++,q++){
        array[p]=array[q];
        printf("%c",array[p]);
    }
    array[b-a-1]='\0';
```

---

<sup>*</sup>The condition `p<b-a-1` is ignore because of the comma character. You probably  want `&` between the conditions but they are equivalent, one of them is enough.